# Prove Completeness of ordered field

Tags: real-analysis

Can we prove completeness  given that "in an ordered field, every strictly monotone increasing sequence bounded above converges"?

Comment: I don't know why you bother with $X$ and $Y$, your statement is equivalent to saying "if $x\in\mathbb R$, $y\in\mathbb R$, $x\le y$, then there exists $c\in\mathbb R$ such that $x\le c\le y$." And it is trivially true, because we can take $c=x$ or $c=y$. If we are assuming an ordered field, we can also take $c=\frac{x+y}2$.

Comment: Maybe what you meant is: If *for all* $x \in X, y \in Y$, we have $x \le y$, then there is $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that *for all* $x \in X, y \in Y$, we have $x \le c \le y$?

Comment: If that's what you meant, then for one direction, if you have the completeness axiom, then given two such sets $X,Y$, $c := \sup X$ will work.  For the other direction, if you have your statement, then given a set $X$ which is bounded above, let $Y$ be the set of upper bounds of $X$, and then your statement's $c$ will have to be a least upper bound of $X$.

Comment: Deleted the wrong statement of Dedekind Property. Thanks to Daniel, bof and Chris

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you've got the statement right?  As written, this is significantly weaker than completeness (for instance, it holds if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: I'm not sure... How should I modify it? Does it require the intersection of X and Y to be empty?